# How to keep drop down option selected in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

The selected text is not staying selected in a drop down menu on my order page.

I've added a drop down menu to our order page to select the words "UPS Account Number, or "FedEx Account Number". Then an input box gets displayed for the user to type in their account number. I am using the onChange event with this drop down menu. This works fine on a page by itself, but when I try to use it on our order page, the selected text in the drop down menu does not stay selected. If I change the cfset to page.ShipAcctMethod, it errors out.

```
<cfif isDefined('form.ShipAcctMethod') 
    AND form.ShipAcctMethod NEQ "">
   <cfset form.ShipAcctMethod = form.ShipAcctMethod>
</cfif>
<select name="ShipAcctMethod" required="yes" onChange="this.form.submit()">
   <option value="" selected>Shipping Account</option>
   <option value="UPSNumber" <cfif isDefined('page.ShipAcctMethod') 
        and form.ShipAcctMethod eq 'UPSNumber'>selected</cfif>>
       UPS Account Number
   </option>
   <option value="FedExNumber" <cfif isDefined('page.ShipAcctMethod') 
        and form.ShipAcctMethod eq 'FedExNumber'>selected</cfif>>
      FedEx Account Number
   </option>
</select>
<br><br>

<!--- Choose a selection --->
<cfif isDefined('form.ShipAcctMethod') and 
        form.ShipAcctMethod eq 'UPSNumber'>
    <input type="text"  maxlength="100"  
       size="30"name="UPSNumber" 
       placeholder="UPS Account Number" required>
    </td>
    </tr>

<cfelseif isDefined('form.ShipAcctMethod') 
       and form.ShipAcctMethod eq 'FedExNumber'>
    <input type="text"  maxlength="100"  
       size="30"name="FedExNumber" 
       placeholder="FedEx Account Number" required>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

I need the selected text to stay selected because this is a requirement the user has to choose. How do I get the selected text to stay selected?

Comment: *it errors out.* Please [edit] the question to include the actual error message. Did you mean to use the FORM scope here? `isDefined('page.ShipAcctMethod')`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have the ability to comment since I don't have a 50 reputation, so I'm providing this as an answer.  As Ageax said, the problem is because `isDefined('page.ShipAcctMethod')` should be `isDefined('form.ShipAcctMethod')`.  Because of this, the condition will always evaluate to false and the "selected" attribute never gets set for those options.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid (and correct) answer.  @Andy - Taking it a step further, you could eliminate all of the `IsDefined()` calls by assigning a default value. i.e. `<cfparam name="form.ShipAcctMethod" default="">`. The code would work exactly the same and be a little less bulky to boot. ;-)